# Sorting an array of hashes of hash with respect to innermost hash's value in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array of hashes of hash like following:

```
[
        {
            "value"=>10,
            "inner_hash"=>{
                "name"=>"cc",
            }
        },
        {
            "value"=>14,
            "inner_hash"=>{
                "name"=>"vv",
            }
        },
        {
            "value"=>12,
            "inner_hash"=>{
                "name"=>"mm",
            }
        },
        {
            "value"=>11,
            "inner_hash"=>{
                "name"=>"pp",
            }
        }
    ]
```

I want to sort this array based on the `inner_hash`'s value of `name` key. How do I do it in Ruby?

Expected output:

```
[
        {
            "value"=>10,
            "inner_hash"=>{
                "name"=>"cc",
            }
        },
        {
            "value"=>12,
            "inner_hash"=>{
                "name"=>"mm",
            }
        },
        {
            "value"=>11,
            "inner_hash"=>{
                "name"=>"pp",
            }
        },
        {
            "value"=>14,
            "inner_hash"=>{
                "name"=>"vv",
            }
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
foo.sort_by { |x| x['inner_hash']['name'] }
```